# How to get a list of roles for a user in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want a command that writes all of the roles for a user that writes this command and i can't figure out how to do that.
I have that command :

```
@client.command(name='role')
async def role(context):
    roles = []
    .... (fill the list with all the roles of the context.author)
    await context.send(roles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Member.roles` attribute

```py
@client.command(name='role')
async def role(context):
    roles = context.author.roles # Is already a list of `discord.Role` instances
    await context.send(roles)
```

Note: The command must be invoked in a guild, otherwise it's not gonna work

#### Reference:

- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)